# Why do certain spots on my tiles break my animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://rockforddriveline.com/newrdl/index.html

Well, I don't even know where to begin. I don't even know whats broken. Its just *is* broken. Below the header, there are 5 tiles. In specific spots (*and I mean specific*) on those tiles, when you click, it breaks the animation and causes the description div to appear prematurely. I can't figure out whats causing it. I can't tell you where to click to make this happen, because the spots change depending on resolution and browser. I've managed to produce this problem across Chrome and Firefox, and I assume IE and Opera will do it as well.

If you're running in Chrome or Firefox on a 1080p monitor, than you should take your clicks to the second tile, and click on and around the word "small".
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qX0l.jpg

```
function bannerFader(currentBanner, otherBanners, expandButton, appendInfo){
var disableHover = false;

    $('.append-product-button').hide();
    $(currentBanner).mouseenter(function(){
        if (disableHover == false) {
            $(otherBanners).stop('hoverEvent');
            $(otherBanners).fadeTo(200, .8).queue(null,'hoverEvent');
            $(otherBanners).dequeue();
        }
    });
    $(currentBanner).mouseleave(function(){
        if (disableHover == false) {
            $(otherBanners).stop('hoverEvent');
            $(otherBanners).fadeTo(200, 1).queue('hoverEvent');
            $(otherBanners).dequeue();
        };
    });
    $(expandButton).click(function(){
        disableHover = true;
        $(otherBanners).hide(200, function(){
            $(appendInfo).show(500)
            $('.banner-button').hide();
            $('.append-product-button').show();
        });
    });
    $('#sub, #heading, .append-product-button').click(function(){
        if (disableHover == true) {
            $(appendInfo).hide(300,function(){
                $(otherBanners).show(200);
                $('.banner-one, .banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-five').fadeTo(0, 1);
                $('.banner-button').show();
                disableHover = false;
            });

        };
    });
};

function autoRunner() {
    bannerFader('.banner-one', '.banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-five', '.banner-one','.append-one')
    bannerFader('.banner-two', '.banner-one, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-five', '.banner-two','.append-two')
    bannerFader('.banner-three', '.banner-two, .banner-one, .banner-four, .banner-five', '.banner-three','.append-three')
    bannerFader('.banner-four', '.banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-one, .banner-five', '.banner-four','.append-four')
    bannerFader('.banner-five', '.banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-one', '.banner-five','.append-five')
};
```

**EDIT 7/31/14:** The glitch can be produced across all updated browsers on 1920x1080.

Comment: Works perfectly for me on Opera 21, screen res 1600x900

Comment: My co-worker is running 1600x900, and he managed to do it on Chrome and Firefox. I'll test Opera.